# How can I recover my Boot?

Tags: boot

Since last week I am trying to recover my Boot. 
After the last update for Ubuntu 12.04 I lost it and nobody could help me, up to now, despite of trying to.
I used Boot-repair but there are problems with dependences, which can't be fix. 
Here the Boot-Repair info:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11884313/

I will be very grateful if somebody could help me. I am Co-Administrator of a Fan Page and this issue don't let me use my normal operating system and it represents a big problem to me.

Comment: What happens when you try to boot?

Comment: Black Screen with Grub> Prompt

Comment: It looks like you had a /boot partition as sda1, but now it is commented out in fstab. When you ran Boot-Repair you must tell it you have a separate partition for /boot for it to correctly update. Also do not install grub to partitions like sda1 and sda2. You only install grub to the MBR of a drive like sda. You also should houseclean old kernels or your /boot will fill up.

Answer (score 0):

Boot with a Live CD/USB or whatever you have. Open a terminal emulator (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I suppose Ubuntu is installed in sda, but if it is not, change sda for whatever it is.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25896/discussion-on-answer-by-eduardo-cola-how-can-i-recover-my-boot).